# How to find g(t) of an initial value problem

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the initial value problem
 $$y′=\begin{bmatrix} 
   4 & 3t \\
   4t^2 & -3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
y +g(t)$$

$$y(1)=\begin{bmatrix} 
   -1 \\
   3\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

We have system of equations :
Suppose we know that
 $$y(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 
   t+α \\
   -3t^2+ β\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

is the unique solution to this initial value problem. Find g(t) and the constants α and β.

[Picture of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JxKo.png)

I was already able to calculate α and β as -2 and 6 respectively, however I'm not sure what to do next to find g(t).

Sorry I am so bad at rendering these equations, but i hope the attached image will help make them clear! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint***

$$y(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 
   t+α \\
   -3t^2+ β\\
  \end{bmatrix} \implies y(1)=\begin{bmatrix} 
   1+α \\
   -3+ β\\
  \end{bmatrix} \implies \begin{bmatrix} 
   α +1\\
   -3+ β\\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 
   -1 \\
   3\\
  \end{bmatrix} \implies \begin{bmatrix} 
  \alpha= -2 \\
   \beta =6\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$g(t)=y′-\begin{bmatrix} 
   4 & 3t \\
   4t^2 & -3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}y
 \implies g(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 \\
   -6t\\
  \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 
   4 & 3t \\
   4t^2 & -3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
   t-2 \\
   -3t^2+ 6\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4):

Just rearrange:
$$g(t)=y'-\begin{bmatrix} 
   4 & 3t \\
   4t^2 & -3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
y.$$